# Lengthy Rails/MySQL query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, resque

I have a query that is hitting a rather large MySQL users table and takes a while to run. It is currently part of a Resque background job. I have been asked to potentially have it hit our MySQL slave database as opposed to production because it will prevent the job from slowing down users that may be signing up in production. I am wondering if this makes sense and if so how I would switch the database I am querying in a specific class?

So far my guess is that I would add something like the below to my Resque job class. Another question I have is if it would only be applicable for that specific class or if it would interfere with other jobs potentially as well and have them point to the wrong place?

```
class ResqueJob
 @queue = :resque_job

 def self.perform(id)
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("slave_database")
   users = User.all (for example)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus). Read also my small demo project here: [Octopus Replication Example](https://github.com/pmatsinopoulos/octopus_replication_example)